# How to calculate the columns adding the value of the previous row in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

What I want to do is, when I select records from the table, the last column is the subtraction of the two columns. Now in the first record, the last column (i.e. Subtraction of two columns) will be `[Value1] - [Value2]` where `[Value1] and [Value2] are columns of the table.

Now the second record will be like below,

```
'Value of (previous row.last column) + ([Value1] - [Value2])
```

and so for the next record and so on.

The columns are as below,

```
[ID],[Value1],[Value2]
```

Now the records will be like below,

```
[ID]    [Value1]    [Value2]    [Result]
 1       10           5          10 - 5 = 5
 2       15           7          5 + (15 - 7) = 13
 3       100          50         13 + (100 - 50) = 63
 and so on......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support running totals, but for your data and your desired result it's possible to factor out the arithmetic and write the query like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.value1, t.value2, SUM(t1.value1 - t1.value2) 
FROM table1 AS t 
JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t.id >= t1.id 
GROUP BY t.id, t.value1, t.value2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/efaf1/2/0

This query will slow down as your row count increases. So, if you're planning to run this on a large table, you may want to run the calculation outside of SQLite.